# Simple animation library for a bit of flash

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# winforms project and I want to add a bit of jQuery or iPhone style animation flash to it.

Nothing too fancy just an easy way to slide and expand panels, perhaps a bit of rotation.

Is there a library out there that would do this all for me?

Comment: Which .net version are you on ?

Comment: The app is currently in .net 2, but I just want to use it to demo a few ideas, so any version would be fine. It would be good to encourage those on high that upgrading is actually worthwhile!

Comment: Yeah, it's always good to have a carrot you can dangle in front of them to keep them moving along.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also inject WPF controls into your WinForms apps if you're wanting to add stuff in to an existing project.  [Here's](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms) a good tutorial on how it's done.

I'm not sure if it would work for drawing 3D or rotating (although it might), but you can def use WPF in your WinForms.  I haven't tried using the expander myself, but other controls I've used worked just fine.

Comment: Very useful link - I didnt know you could do that!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using .NET 3.5 you can use [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx) to achieve animations.

Comment: he would have to replace large parts of his application if he is using winforms now...